# How to use lower Elastic search version in Maven when using "spring-boot-starter-parent"

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-webflux

I am using "spring-boot-starter-parent" with version "2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT" for Webflux. I am using Elasticsearch as datasource. So i have included "spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch" in pom.xml. This is by default including ES version of 5.4.0. But my Elasticsearch version is 2.3.1. I cannot upgrade my ES version now. So is there a way to downgrade ES version which is getting included by default (5.4.0) to lower version (2.3.1). I tried specifying lower version in "spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch" dependency in pom.xml, but still not working. I am getting "NoNodeAvailalbe Exception". So I downgraded ES by using dependency "org.elasticsearch" with version 2.3.1, but in this case I am not able to bring up my server.

Comment: Are you using spring-boot-starter-parent as your Maven project's parent?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson yes i am using spring-boot-starter-parent

Answer (score 1):

You can use maven `dependencyManagement` tag to override `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` or `org.elasticsearch` version.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

See this detailed post from spring.io [Overriding Dependency Versions with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot)

Comment: It's not that simple. The version of Spring Data Elasticsearch that Spring Boot 2.0 uses requires Elasticsearch 5